# Postgres group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I run a query, these are the results presented to me:

```
id  account_id  score  active  item_id
5    78          9      true    4
6    78          1      true    4
7    78          9      true    6
8    78          5      true    7
9    78          5      true    8
10   78          5      true    8
```

I'd like the output to look like this by combining item_id's based on score:

```
id  account_id  score  active  item_id
*    78          10      true    4
7    78          9      true    6
8    78          5      true    7
*    78          10      true    8
```

My query that returns that info looks like this:

```
SELECT item.id, item.account_id, itemaudit.score, itemrevision.active, itemaudit.item_id
from item 
left join itemrevision on item.id = itemrevision.id 
join itemaudit on item.id = itemaudit.id 
where itemrevision.active = true 
;
```

The bit I'm missing is when 'item_id' is not distinct, combine/sum the value of 'score'. I'm not sure how to do this step.

The schema looks like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE item
(id integer, account_id integer);

CREATE TABLE itemaudit
(id integer, item_id integer, score integer);

CREATE TABLE itemrevision
(id int, active boolean, item_id int);


INSERT INTO item 
  (id, account_id)
VALUES
    (5, 78),
    (6, 78),
    (7, 78),
    (8, 78),
    (9, 78),
    (10, 78)    
;


INSERT INTO itemaudit
    (id, item_id, score)
VALUES
    (5, 4, 5),
    (6, 4, 1),
    (7, 6, 9),
    (8, 7, 10),
    (9, 8, 1),
    (10, 8, 9)  
;

INSERT INTO itemrevision
    (id, active, item_id)
VALUES
    (5, true, 4),
    (6, true, 4),
    (7, true, 6),
    (8, true, 7),
    (9, true, 7),
    (10, true, 8)
;
```

Comment: what do you want the output of that query to be?

Comment: Why did you revert my edit? I added the `CREATE TABLE AS` for you...

Comment: I reverted the edit because it gave the impression that data was in an existing table while in fact its the results of a query across several different ables. I wanted to avoid that confusion.

Comment: That's not how the site works, either those details are relevant to the question or they're not. No one can answer now because you've supplied a grid and asked a question on SQL. You've put the burden on those answering the question to get your environment, schema, and data working. Even worse, having done that work for them you've decided that they should all have to do that work for themselves when you deleted my edit. If those details relevant show us a gird (or preferably a `CREATE TABLE AS` from all relevant tables that your query hits).

Comment: Let's take it a step back. How is that output relevant to your question?

Comment: That's the output I get from my initial query. Its not desirable. I want the output of my query to look like the output at the bottom of my question. I'll edit to demonstrate this better.

Comment: Not making it personal, but is it useful to put a query that generates output, and the output it generates if you don't want that output? And to withhold the schema and data it operates on?

Comment: muchh better.  ( I would delete the grid and bad query and just leave that and what you want.)

Comment: In the example you have an item that has no item_audit, what do you want to happen there? The example also doesn't line up with what you want.

Comment: The values in the schema are fake values. The values from my two grids are real output. I'll try and clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just want an aggregation query:

```
select ia.item_id, sum(ia.score) as score
from item i join  -- the `where` clause turns this into an inner join
     itemrevision ir
     on i.id = ir.id  join
     itemaudit ia
     on i.id = ia.id 
where ir.active = true 
group by ia.item_id;
```

Notes:

- I changed the `left join` to an `inner join`, because the `where` clause has this effect anyway.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- In an aggregation query, the other columns are not appropriate.

Comment: That solved the initial problem, thank you! Is there a way to retain the structure I showed in my example but combine 'item_id' rows and add their score into that row?

Comment: I've added an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this..

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN array_length(array_agg(id),1) = 1
      THEN (array_agg(id))[1]::text
    ELSE '*'
  END AS id,
  account_id,
  sum(score) AS score,
  item_id
FROM item
GROUP BY account_id, item_id
ORDER BY account_id, item_id;

 id | account_id | score | item_id 
----+------------+-------+---------
 *  |         78 |    10 |       4
 7  |         78 |     9 |       6
 8  |         78 |     5 |       7
 *  |         78 |    10 |       8
(4 rows)
```

While this is what you want the simpler versions is more detailed and better.

```
SELECT
  array_agg(id) AS id,
  account_id,
  sum(score) AS score,
  item_id
FROM item
GROUP BY account_id, item_id
ORDER BY account_id, item_id;

   id   | account_id | score | item_id 
--------+------------+-------+---------
 {5,6}  |         78 |    10 |       4
 {7}    |         78 |     9 |       6
 {8}    |         78 |     5 |       7
 {9,10} |         78 |    10 |       8
(4 rows)
```